# React-native: Undefined is not an object ... when using 'react-native-tts'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I want to use text to speech for my react-native app, so I imported  [react-native-tts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tts)

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
import Tts from 'react-native-tts';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._pressConfig = this._pressConfig.bind(this);
    this._pressPlay = this._pressPlay.bind(this);
  }
  _pressConfig() {
    console.log("pressed");
  }
  _pressPlay() {
    Tts.speak("Hello world");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.navigation}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._pressConfig}>
            <Image source={require('./App/img/img_hamburger.png')}
              style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._pressPlay}>
            <Image source={require('./App/img/img_play.png')}
              style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and I got this error when tap on play button:
[image]

I have tried install, update, clean ... every npm packages but nothing helps. Can anyone help me with my issue? I am totally new to React Native so I really appreciate any advice.

Comment: did you run `react-native link` after install the package?

Comment: @Harlan yes, I do exactly same steps as it shows in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tts

Comment: did you come across a solution for this? oddly, i cannot find TextToSpeech documented in any native modules.

Comment: found my mistake. project needed a full rebuild after linking the texttospeech module.